# SQL get products and messages group by

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to write a Oracle SQL query. I have two tables products and messages. Product table looks like this:

| product_id | creation_date | user_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2017-03-01 | u1 | c1 |
| p2 | 2018-05-23 | u1 | c3 |
| p3 | 2019-06-21 | u2 | c1 |

messages table looks like this:

| message_id | creation_date | product_id | user_from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | 2018-03-01 | p1 | u2 |
| m2 | 2019-08-19 | p1 | u5 |
| m3 | 2020-10-10 | p3 | u7 |

I want to list all the products within a category, sorted by their total number of messages, together with their top 5 buyers of each product (users who contacted those products sorted by their total number of messages sent)

Sample output table:

| category_id | product_id | total_messages_for_product | user_id | messages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | p1 | 200 | u1 | 10 |
| c1 | p1 | 200 | u2 | 9 |
| c1 | p1 | 200 | u3 | 7 |
| c1 | p1 | 200 | u4 | 5 |
| c1 | p1 | 200 | u5 | 4 |
| c1 | p2 | 150 | u7 | 11 |
| c1 | p2 | 150 | u8 | 10 |
| c1 | p2 | 150 | u9 | 9 |
| c1 | p2 | 150 | u10 | 7 |
| c1 | p2 | 150 | u4 | 6 |

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Your existing input data doesn't make sense. Why is there a **`user_id`** column in the **`products`** table?

Comment: I know how to get category_id, product_id and group by sum messages by using an inner join, I don't know how to get the last two columns @Russ

Comment: @mathguy the product is created by some user, however this user_id is different from the messages user_from column which shows the user who sent the message. hope it clarifies

Comment: But then, I am just guessing, you want `user_from` in the output (from the second table), not `user_id`. Right?

Comment: yes exactly @mathguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want:

```sql
SELECT p.category_id,
       p.product_id,
       m.total_messages_for_product,
       m.user_from AS user_id,
       m.messages
FROM   products p
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT product_id,
                user_from,
                COUNT(*) AS messages,
                SUM( COUNT(*) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id )
                  AS total_messages_for_product,
                RANK() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                ) AS messages_rank
         FROM   messages
         GROUP BY product_id, user_from
       ) m
       ON ( p.product_id = m.product_id )
WHERE  m.messages_rank <= 5;
```

*(Note: you could, instead, use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the top 5 entries without ties rather than `RANK` which returns the top 5 entries with ties.)*

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products ( product_id, creation_date, user_id, category_id ) AS
SELECT 'p1', DATE '2017-03-01', 'u1', 'c1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p2', DATE '2018-05-23', 'u1', 'c3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p3', DATE '2019-06-21', 'u2', 'c1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE messages( message_id, creation_date, product_id, user_from ) AS
SELECT 'm1', DATE '2018-03-01', 'p1', 'u2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'm2', DATE '2019-08-19', 'p1', 'u5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'm3', DATE '2020-10-10', 'p3', 'u7' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CATEGORY_ID | PRODUCT_ID | TOTAL_MESSAGES_FOR_PRODUCT | USER_ID | MESSAGES
> :---------- | :--------- | -------------------------: | :------ | -------:
> c1          | p1         |                          2 | u5      |        1
> c1          | p1         |                          2 | u2      |        1
> c1          | p3         |                          1 | u7      |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=067971d87d7f7810bfbdcea38b828512)*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested, since you didn't provide test data in a usable form):

```
with
  agg (product_id, user_from, messages, total_messages_for_product) as (
    select product_id, user_from, count(*),
           sum(count(*)) over (partition by product_id)
    from   messages
    group  by product_id, user_from
  )
select p.category_id, a.product_id, a.total_messages_for_product,
       a.user_from, a.messages
from   products p join agg a on p.product_id = a.product_id
order  by product_id, user_from   --  if/as needed
;
```

The main work is done in the `agg` subquery (using only the `messages` table). Notice the use of the analytic `sum()` function, partitioned by product, to get the total messages by product. Then you get the `category_id` by joining to the `products` table.